# What's the fastest client-side method to determine if an Azure mobile service table is empty?

Tags: sql-server, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on a UWP app that needs to check to see if a mobile service table has any records.

I realize I could do something like this and check to see if any records are returned:

```
records = await MyTable.Select(x => x).ToCollectionAsync();
```

However, is there a way to do this that won't attempt to download every record into a collection?  What would be great is if something like this were allowed, but it isn't:

```
setupOfferors = await setupOfferorsTable.Select(so => so).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to applie the specified take clause to the source query and execute this query to see if it will return data. `await setupOfferorsTable.Select(so => so).Take(1).ToCollectionAsync()`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Have you solved your issue by my suggestion?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  It is much faster than the method I was using.

Comment: Ok. I will make a reply on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method for you to check if the Azure mobile service table is empty. But you could try to apply the specified take clause to the source query and execute this query to see if it will return data.

For example:

```
await setupOfferorsTable.Select(so => so).Take(1).ToCollectionAsync();
```